# Superimposing asymmetric t-distribution using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I'm trying to show whether the asymmetric t-distribution or a normal distribution fits a certain dataset better. In doing this I decided to superimpose both a fitted normal distribution and a fitted t-distribution. For the normal distribution this is no problem using stat_fun:

```
    x <- data.frame(rnorm(500))
    names(x) <- c("test.data")

    ggplot(x,aes(x=test.data))  +  
      stat_function(fun = dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(x$test.data,na.rm=TRUE),
      sd=sd(x$test.data,na.rm=TRUE)), aes(colour = 'Normal')) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), alpha = 0.4)
```

Which yields the graph below:

[image]

Now I want to do the same for the asymmetric t-distribution, where I have a shape (nu), location (mu), dispersion (sigma) and non-centrality parameter (gamma). If I enter the t-distribution in the stat_function function I can only specify the shape and non-centrality parameter, using the dt function from the package stats.

Is there any way to superimpose a t-distribution over my histogram where I can pre-specify all four parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(rt(5000,df=5,ncp=1)*10+7)
names(x) <- c("test.data")

# Define a Student t distribution with shape (nu) and location (mu)
dt2 <- function(x, mu, nu, df, ncp) {
  dt((x-mu)/nu,df,ncp)/nu
}

ggplot(x,aes(x=test.data))  +  
stat_function(fun = dt2, args=list(mu=7, nu=10, df=5, ncp=1), 
              aes(colour = 'Student t'), lwd=1) +
geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins=100, alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]